# Issue with Populating dropdown from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysqli

hi using following php code I am trying to populate a dropbox from mysql database:

```
enter code here
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
   die('Unable to connect!');
 }
else
{
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM language';
  if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
   {
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
     {
 ?>
   <p> Select a language
    <select id="selectLanguage">
    <option value="">select</option>
 <?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 {
  ?>
  <option value='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'><?php echo $row[1]; ?></option>
 <?php
  }
   ?>
 </select>
 </p>
  <p id="result"></p>
 <?php
  }
 else
  {
   echo 'No records found!';
   }
 $result->close();
   }
  else
   {
      echo 'Error in query: $query. '.$mysqli->error;
    }
   }
   $mysqli->close();
   ?>
```

I am not getting any error but the dropbox populated by this message instead of cell values stored in database:
**(!) Notice : Undefined offset:0 in C:\wamp\test\index.ph on line 40 Call Stack#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0009684656{main}()...\index.php:0'>**
can you please let me know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You problem is here:

```
<option value='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'><?php echo $row[1]; ?></option>
```

you fetch the data using an associated array. not an index array.

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

You get that error message because index "1" does not exist.

Comment: Thansk jaechuleta, but I have two column in my table! id and name so I have the index 1, am i right? if not can you please let me know how I can fix the error?

Comment: what does print_r($row); exit(); output? put it right after the while.

Comment: Ok I did like this <?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
print_r($row); exit();
{
?> and it just print out the empty dropdown without any error message

Comment: when you do the print $row view the source and look at the output, then paste that here.